# Entity Framework, execute a Stored Procedure and Variable WHERE Clause

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, dynamic, where-clause

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with EF and a variable `WHERE` clause.

What I first thought was this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP  
   @WHEREClause VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @SQL Varchar(8000)
   SET @SQL ='Select ...' + @WHEREClause 
   EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Problem here EF wont recognize the selected values from the stored procedure anymore.

So I think of something like that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP  
    @WHEREClause VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select ... FROM ... @WHEREClause 
END
```

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, creating a WHERE clause like this could leave you vulnerable to SQL injection. You might be able to do it safer by using LINQ to narrow down the data rather than a dynamically built WHERE.

Another way to handle it is to use the [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) method (this is Database.SqlQuery in EF5). This will allow you to load the results of the stored procedure into a POCO object. You can also parametrize the query which might make it safer, depending on how it's constructed.